# Data modeling in GLPK - plain data syntax?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, ampl, glpk

I'm trying to solve a linear optimization problem in GLPK. I have a set of n vertices in a graph, n*n edges, and a specific weight for each edge. I need to try it with a few different data sets of n vertices and weights. However, I'm having a lot of trouble with the GLPK syntax when trying to input the model data into my program. I'm trying to do something like:

```
param n := [number];

param weight := [matrix in plain text...];
```

(The weight matrix is just a vertex*vertex matrix where weight[i][j] is the weight of the edge from vertex i to vertex j)

It obviously doesn't work since GLPK asks for a label for each line and column in the matrix, by default.  The GLPK manual lists a "plain-data" specifier but no example in how to use it. Is it possible to just list the matrix and assign each value to the correct weight[i][j] field? If so, what's the syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table data format to provide a data for a two-dimensional parameter, for example:

```
param n;
param weight{1..n, 1..n};

data;

param n := 2;

param weight:
     1  2 :=
  1 11 12
  2 21 22;

display weight;
```

Comment: Yeah, this works fine for a smaller number of nodes, but the data sets I've been given don't include the line and column numbers, and it would be really hard to add them for like 400+ nodes each time. (In your example, what I have is just the [11 12 21 22] for example)

Comment: You can use the AMPL read command to input data in custom format but I'm not sure it works with glpk/mathprog.

Comment: Great idea. I went ahead and tried this but unfortunately it looks like GLPK doesn't include this function from AMPL...

Comment: Too bad. Then I'd use a script to convert the data in the format with the explicit keys GLPK can understand.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing. Seems weird that there wouldn't be an option to just input the plain data but, oh well...